# A sum of a function and its derivatives at a point

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

> Let f be a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ satisfying $$f(x)=-(x^2-x+1)e^2+\int_0^x e^{x-y}f’(y)dy$$
> If $f(1)+f’(1)+f''(1)=ke$, find $k$.

What I did: Call $\int_0^x e^{-y}f’(y)dy $ as $u$. Call $\int_0^1e^{-y}f’(y)dy$ as $u_1$.
$$f(x)=-(x^2-x+1)e^2+\int_0^x e^{x-y}f'(y)dy$$
$f(1)=-e^2+eu_1$,
$$f’(x)=-(2x-1)e^2+e^x(u+e^{-x}f’(x))$$
So $(2x-1)e^2=e^xu$. At x=1, $e^2=eu_1$, so $f’(1)=0$. (Is this useless?)
$$f''(x)=-2e^2+e^x(u+e^{-x}f'(x)+e^{-x}f''(x))$$
So $f'(x)=-e^xu+2e^2$ so $f'(1)=2e^2-eu_1$

So far, $f(1)+f'(1)=e^2$  How to find $f'(1)$? Is there anything which directly gives the sum $f(1)+f'(1)+f''(1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has $$\displaystyle{f(x)=-(x^2-x+1)e^2+e^x\int_0^x e^{-y}f’(y)dy} \quad \quad \quad (*)$$ By direct computation, you get
\begin{align*} f'(x)& =-(2x-1)e^2 + e^x \int_0^x e^{-y}f’(y)dy + e^x e^{-x}f'(x) \\ & = -(2x-1)e^2 + e^x \int_0^x e^{-y}f’(y)dy + f'(x) \end{align*}

which simplifies and gives that $\displaystyle{ -(2x-1)e^2 + e^x \int_0^x e^{-y}f’(y)dy = 0}$, i.e. that $$e^x\int_0^x e^{-y}f’(y)dy =(2x-1)e^{2}$$

With this information, $(*)$ becomes $$f(x)= -(x^2-x+1)e^2+(2x-1)e^2 = e^2(-x^2+3x-2)$$

and you get successively $f'(x)=e^2(-2x+3)$ and $f''(x)=-2e^2$, so
$$f(1)+f'(1)+f''(1)=0+e^2-2e^2 = -e^2$$

so $$\boxed{f(1)+f'(1)+f''(1)=ke \quad \text{where} \quad k=-e}$$